# Laravel shows 'Permission denied' after local package added

Tags: php, laravel

I have successfully installed Laravel 8 in Ubuntu 20.4 (Apache server) and the home page is shown correctly. Then, I have added my local repository to `composer.json`:

```json
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "/home/kari/kama-web-service"
    }
  ]
```

and it successfully have installed `composer require mypackage/name`:

```
.
.
Discovered Package: mypackage/name
.
.
```

after that the following error is shown on home page:

```
ErrorException: include(/var/www/html/rws2/vendor/composer/../mypackage/name/src/KamaWebServiceProvider.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in file /var/www/html/rws2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 480

#0 /var/www/html/rws2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(480): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions-&gt;handleError()
#1 /var/www/html/rws2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(480): include()
#2 /var/www/html/rws2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(346): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#3 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader-&gt;loadClass()
#4 /var/www/html/rws2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(735): spl_autoload_call()
#5 /var/www/html/rws2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(669): Illuminate\Foundation\Application-&gt;resolveProvider()
#6 /var/www/html/rws2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php(75): Illuminate\Foundation\Application-&gt;register()
#7 /var/www/html/rws2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(649): Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository-&gt;load()
#8 /var/www/html/rws2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application-&gt;registerConfiguredProviders()
#9 /var/www/html/rws2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(237): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders-&gt;bootstrap()
#10 /var/www/html/rws2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(152): Illuminate\Foundation\Application-&gt;bootstrapWith()
#11 /var/www/html/rws2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(136): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;bootstrap()
#12 /var/www/html/rws2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;sendRequestThroughRouter()
#13 /var/www/html/rws2/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;handle()
#14 {main}
```

I'm absolutely sure that the file `/var/www/html/rws2/vendor/composer/../mypackage/name/src/KamaWebServiceProvider.php` exists.

At first I thought that I should give `rw` access to my package at `/home/kari/kama-web-service` so I ran `chmod -R 775 /home/kari/kama-web-service` and `sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /home/kari/kama-web-service` commands but nothing happen!

Any idea?

Comment: for example i am using windows my project located in following path  I:\\xampp\\htdocs\\payment

so url will be 

I:\\xampp\\htdocs\\payment\\packages/John/Validation

   "repositories": {
        "john/opayo": {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "I:\\xampp\\htdocs\\payment\\packages/John/Validation",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

The problem goes back to the issue of ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`/home/kari` permissions. To solve it I ran also:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /home/kari
```